# Getting a null value not expected for user defined function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I'm stuck trying to create a function to display customer names based on area code.

Function is created, but I'm getting null results for known area codes where I should be getting lots.

I'm a clueless newbie, and that may be a factor.

```
alter function ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode(@AreaCode nvarchar(3))
returns nvarchar(100)
as
begin
declare @Customer as nvarchar(100);
set @Customer =
    (
        select c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName
        from SalesLT.Address as a
        join SalesLT.CustomerAddress as ca
        on a.AddressID = ca.AddressID
        join SalesLT.Customer as c
        on ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        where left(a.PostalCode,3) = @AreaCode
    )
    return @Customer
    end
```

Using the command

select dbo.ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode(706)

I'm getting null results. The table has lots of 706 area codes.

Comment: If the table has lots of 706 codes, how can `@Customer` hold them all?  Don't you need to return 1 value from the select?

Comment: Have you tried executing the select statement outside of the function to see if it works?

Comment: It doesn't, it gives me no column name and no rows affected. And you're right, about @customer, I didn't think of that... but apparently I'm not even making it to that problem yet.

Comment: You are filtering on left 3 chars of PostalCode (a.k.a. zip code), I think you meant to use left 3 chars of Phone Number instead since that is what area code is related too?

Comment: So, this isn't a user defined functions problem, it's a select not working problem. Someone else here briefly posted a comment that your joins may not be working - do you have correct matching data in all tables - query each one, working "upwards" to check which values you get, and plugging them into the next query on one table. You may find that the are no rows in `CustomerAddress` which match for example.

Comment: I don't know which database you are using, but also try changing the `WHERE` to a `AND`.

Comment: Another note - you are invoking the function with a number, but the processing assumes a string.

Comment: Whoops. Somehow I deleted my comment. Not sure how I did that. I suggested that the issue may be that you're doing [inner joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) on these tables. In other words, your customer will require a record in each of those tables, that matches your criteria, for something to return. Is that your expectation? Also, is BateTech onto something re: area code vs postal code? This is in addition to the problems with your function, which you're already aware of and these other guys have pointed out.

Comment: Also, you have created a scalar function, so after you change to filter on area code instead of postal code, and if there is more than one customer with the 706 area code, you will likely get an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." If you are wanting to retrieve all customers that have a certain area code, then you will need a table value function.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: alter function ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode(@AreaCode nvarchar(3))
returns table
return
    (
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Customers
   from SalesLT.Customer
   where left(Phone, 3) = @AreaCode
    ) is what I'm currently trying, getting Msg 2010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode, Line 29
Cannot perform alter on 'ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode' because it is an incompatible object type.

Comment: You have to drop the existing scalar function first. `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects o WHERE o.object_id = object_id('ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode') and o.type in ('FN','IF')) DROP FUNCTION ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode;`  and then change the `ALTER` to `CREATE`.

Comment: Also if you do not want duplicate customer names returned, then add `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` in your function.

Comment: --create function ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode(@AreaCode nvarchar(3))
--returns table
--return
--    (
--select distinct FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Customers
--   from SalesLT.Customer
--   where left(Phone, 3) = @AreaCode
--    ) gets me Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
Invalid object name 'dbo.udfGetCustomerByAreaCode'.

Comment: I had the wrong function name in the select, see my answer posted below for update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering on left 3 chars of PostalCode (a.k.a. zip code), I think you meant to use left 3 chars of Phone Number instead since that is where you find the area code.

Also, you have created a scalar function, so after you change to filter on area code instead of postal code, and if there is more than one customer with the 706 area code, you will likely get the following error:

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

If you are wanting to retrieve all customers that have a certain area code, then you will need a table value function. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx

If you do not want duplicate customer names returned, then add DISTINCT after the SELECT in your function.

Note that when selecting from a table valued function, you should use the syntax

```
SELECT Customers FROM dbo.ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode('706')
```

instead of

```
SELECT dbo.ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode('706')
```

Comment: I had the wrong function name in the select, updated to `ufnGetCustomerByAreaCode` instead of `udfGetCustomerByAreaCode`

Comment: Yeah I should have caught that... should have caught a lot of things. Thanks for the help everyone, everything things to work now!